# Need a function to avoid repeating numerical sequence

Tags: actionfunction

I need a function to avoid repeating numerical sequence.
The PO number in my form is a numbered series and I can not have any number duplication (each PO has a unique number that follows a numerical sequence)
Appreciate any help

Comment: Can't you use Autonumber for that?

Comment: not in form assembly 
must write a piece of code for that

Comment: Are you talking about Salesforce? Which form assembly do you mean?

Comment: https://www.formassembly.com/
you can use it to create online forms and sync it with Salesforce fields

Comment: if formassembly.com allows you to select Salesforce fields, why can't you select AutoNumber fields? You don't need code for that at all

Comment: tried to do that. I couldn't :( 
but thanks for the answer, it is the only solution

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use Standard AutoNumber name field as your PO Number. It can be numbered series without number duplication

Comment: yeah , it works in SQL, mySql and etc. but not in form assembly tools